# Issues defining probability measure for a conditioned experiment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ I have three coins in my pocket, labeled $a,b$ and $c$. The probabilities with which the coins give tails are $1/2,1/3,3/4,$ respectively. I grab one coin out of the three at random 
>   and I flip it twice.
>
> Define a probability space that models the choice of coin and the outcomes of the coin flips.

$\textbf{Thoughts and Concerns:}$ For the sample space I have the following somewhat obvious model
$$\Omega=\{(x,y_1,y_2)\,:\,x\in\{a,b,c\}\text{ and }y_i\in\{H,T\}\}.$$
Upon noticing that $\Omega$ has finite cardinality, we see that we may take our $\sigma$-algebra to be $\mathcal F=2^\Omega.$

I am having difficulties when it comes to defining a suitable probability measure.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Any feedback is much appreciated, and I want to thank you for your time.

Comment: It seems like you should have $$\Omega=\{(x,y)\,:\,x\in\{a,b,c\}\text{ and }y\in\{H,T\}\}.$$  Choose a coin and flip it; it comes up either heads or tails.

Comment: @saulspatz I defined the sample space that way due to having to flip the coins twice though, as opposed to only one flip

Comment: I missed "twice" in the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have $12$ points in the probability space, so you just have to specify the probability of each of them.  For example, $(b,T,H)$ should have probability $$\frac13\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac23=\frac{2}{27}$$ Just do the same kind of thing for the other $11$ points.

Comment: You can also define 3 random variables with Binomial distribution. And a forth that is a mixture of the other three based on the outcome of the pocket pick.